# min-height not working with multiple child divs

Tags: html, position, absolute, css

I have a website where i am using height auto to set the height of a content div and min height 100% to make sure the content div always stretches the height of the page.

my HTML looks like this

```
<html>
<body>
 <div id="holder">
  <div id="outercontent">
   <div id="innercontent">
    content goes here
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css rules are as follows

```
html,body {
    height:100%;
    color:white;
}

#holder {
    background-color:transparent;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#outercontent {
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:940px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    background-image:url(../images/bowsides.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#innercontent {
    width:900px;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color:#ffefce;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The holder div is an absolutely positioned DIV, i need this because i have a rotating background which puts each background image on a separate absolutely positioned div. so this div is placed on top of all of them using z-index.

outer content is a little wider than my inner content and this is used to give me space put border images (since css3 border images are not widely supported yet)

inner content is my main content area

min-height 100% works on the holder div (that is the outermost div of the group), but it does not work on outercontent or innercontent in any browser

why is this?

Comment: Is there any point in saying min-height:100%. Why not just say height:100%? Also height:auto is the default value so need to set it. Why does holder have position:absolute? Anyway, if you just tell all the DIVs to be 100% it should work I think.

Comment: The site will be CMS powered which means I cannot guarantee that the height generated by the content would be 100% of a screen height. So i do need the min-height (or other solution) to work.

The holder has position absolute so that it is possible for me to make the content appear on top of the background by using z-index. I needed to do this because the site has a rotating background which has a fade in/out effect. it was necessary for each background image to have its own fixed positioned DIV because DIVs have a opacity property and img tags do not.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try opening the source in IE by using deleveloper tools , I guess something is overriding the height , you will get the exact picture then

Comment: The problem occurs in ALL browsers - not just IE

Comment: I understand , but that would give us an idea what is overriding it